# Applying onClick to Function Array in a For Loop (Each Function executed on each Button Click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Hello people of stackoverflow!

I'm looking to use a button in Javascript to execute an array of functions sequentially (one after the other) ON BUTTON CLICK, not all at once. (see Function DisplayNext below)

At the moment, the functions all execute simultaneously. Can anyone help!? I want to be able to click the button and have each coloured square appear on the screen one after the other, on each button click.

```
function red () {
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="#red";
ctx.fillRect(20,60,23,23);
}

function blue() {
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="#blue";
ctx.fillRect(20,100,23,23);
}

function green() {
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="#green";
ctx.fillRect(20,20,23,23);
}


function functionarray() {
var array_of_functions = [
green,
red,
blue, 
]


for (i = 0; i < array_of_functions.length; i++) {
array_of_functions[i]();
}
}

function displayNext() {
var array_of_functions = [
green,
red,
blue, 
]

for (i = 0; i < array_of_functions.length; i++) {
array_of_functions[i].onclick = array_of_functions[i]();

//array_of_functions[i].onclick();

}
}

<p><button type="button" onclick="displayNext()">On Click, next                 colour</button></p>

</html>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <button type="button" id="myID">next color</button>
    </p>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    red = function red() {
        ctx.fillStyle="#red";
        ctx.fillRect(20,60,23,23);
    },
    blue = function blue() {
        ctx.fillStyle="#blue";
        ctx.fillRect(20,100,23,23);
    },
    green = function green() {
        ctx.fillStyle="#green";
        ctx.fillRect(20,20,23,23);
    },
    lastCall = 0,
    array_of_functions = [green, red, blue],
    displayNext = function displayNext() {
        array_of_functions[lastCall]();
        lastCall += 1;
    };
document.getElementById('myID').addEventListener('click', displayNext);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow - didn't expect a reply so soon! Is this implemented after the function within the 'script' tags? Tried it and it's still not quite working .... Thank you though!

Comment: You want to have the array_of_functions and the lastCall outside of the function displayNext function, instead of creating the array again every click.

Comment: Cleaned up the code a bit so it's (hopefully) clearer.